# Why would an app started by systemd on boot perform differently

Tags: python, systemd

I have a python application that I'm trying to start using systemd. I have my unit file set up and systemd configured to start the app. When I sudo systemctl start my_app.service it starts and everything works fine, however, if I reboot the pi, systemd starts the app, but I get exceptions that I wouldn't, had I started it manually.

The app is trying to communicate with a serial device using the waveshare rs485 can hat. The exceptions I get are related to the crc check done on the communication packets.

The question is, why would starting an app automatically at boot using systemd effect it in this way?

This is what my unit file looks like:

```
[Unit]
Description=TCU Interface
After=dev-ttySC0.device
Requires=dev-ttySC0.device

[Service]
Type=idle
User=bd_admin
WorkingDirectory=~
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/bd_admin/e82_1/M001main.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I've tried different service types including simple and one_shot with the same result. The dev-ttySC0.device is the rs485 hat.

I don't think there is a problem with my code because as I said everything works fine if I start it manually.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Here is an example of the exception I'm getting.

```
2022-10-12 21:42:57,270:ERROR:M002logger:Modbus, get temp main line
The received CRC value is incorrect! Full response = [b'\x01',     b'\x03', b'\x04', b'\x1b', b'\x00', b'\xca', b'7', b'\xeb', b'\xfb']Received CRC = b'\xeb\xfb' Calculated CRC = b'\xeb\xa1'
```

You can see in the exception that there is a discrepancy in the crc from the remote device and the one that I calculate.

Here is the code I use to calculate the CRC. The protocol I'm using is Modbus RTU. The standard for the redundancy check is CRC-16-ANSI.

```
    @staticmethod
def crc_calc(data_bytes):
    """
    takes a bytes list
    for each byte input, the LSBit of the data and current crc are compared. If they are equal the crc is shifted right.
    If they are not equal, the crc is shifted right and XOR'd with the polynomial value.
    This is done for each bit in the data byte, which is why its shifted after each comparison.
    :param data_bytes:
    :return:
    """
    if type(data_bytes) is list:
        data_bytes = b''.join(data_bytes)
    poly = 0xA001
    crc = 0xffff
    for data in data_bytes:
        for i in range(8):
            if crc & 1 == data & 1:
                crc >>= 1
            else:
                crc = (crc >> 1) ^ poly
            data >>= 1
    return int.to_bytes(crc, length=2, byteorder='little')
```

Comment: *"I dont think there is a problem with my code because as I said everything works fine if I start it manually."*.  I would say that the boundary of ***my code*** extends to your `systemd` implementation. That being the case, your Q probably is a better fit for the [U&L SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions).